# what does V8.InvokeApiInterruptCallbacks do?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, v8

what does V8.InvokeApiInterruptCallbacks do? And why it appears in the timeline on every mouse click?

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the code/MCVE I can only guess it might be a bug in devtools. Try measuring the time with devtools closed by using console.time and console.timeEnd or by manually calculating performance.now() delta.

Answer (score 0):

`V8.InvokeApiInterruptCallbacks` means that V8 interrupted JavaScript execution at the request of the embedder (i.e. Blink or DevTools) and executed one or more callbacks provided along with that/those request(s).

I agree that it seems surprising that that would take so long and/or would happen frequently, but without more information I can't even guess as to what the cause might be. A reproducible example would be useful.

Comment: Does the `StackGuard` have anything to do with it?

Comment: No, the StackGuard is just the thing that detects a pending interrupt request.